# (Laravel) Dynamic dependency injection for interface, based on user input

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection, interface, laravel-5

I am currently facing a very interesting dilemma with my architecture and implementation.

I have an interface called `ServiceInterface` which have a method called `execute()`

Then I have two different implementations for this interface: `Service1` and `Service2`, which implements the execute method properly.

I have a controller called `MainController` and this controller has a "type-hint" for the `ServiceInterface` (**dependency injection**), it means that both, `Service1` and `Service2`, can be called as resolution for that dependency injection.

**Now the fun part:**

I do not know which of those implementations to use (`Service1` or `Service2`) because I just know if I can use one or other **based on a user input** from a previous step.

It means the user choose a service and based on that value I know if a can use `Service1` or `Service2`.

I am currently solving the dependency injection using a session value, so depending of the value I return an instance or other, BUT I really think that it is not a good way to do it.

Please, let me know if you faced something similar and, how do you solve it, or what can I do to achieve this in the right way.

Thanks in advance. Please let me know if further information is required.

Comment: A good question.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Finally, after some days of researching and thinking a lot about the best approach for this, using Laravel, I finally solved it.

I have to say that this was especially difficult in `Laravel 5.2` because, in this version, the *Session* middleware only is executed in the controllers used in a route, it means that if for some reason I used a controller (not linked for a rote) and try to get access to the session it is not going to be possible.

So, because I cannot use the session, I decided to use URL parameters. Here you have the solution approach; I hope some of you found it useful.

so, you have an interface:

```
interface Service
{
    public function execute();
}
```

Then a couple of implementations for the interface:

Service one:

```
class ServiceOne implements Service
{
    public function execute()
    {
        .......
    }
}
```

Service two.

```
class ServiceTwo implements Service
{
    public function execute()
    {
        .......
    }
}
```

The interesting part is that I have a controller with a function with a dependency with the Service interface. Still, I need to resolve it dynamically to ServiceOne or ServiceTwo based on user input. So:

The controller

```
class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Service $service, ServiceRequest $request)
    {
        $service->execute();
        .......
    }
}
```

Please note that ServiceRequest, validated that the request already have the parameter that we need to resolve the dependency (call it `'service_name'`)

Now, in the AppServiceProvider we can resolve the dependency in this way:

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        
    }

    public function register()
    {
        //This specific dependency is going to be resolved only if
        //the request has the service_name field stablished
        if(Request::has('service_name'))
        {
            //Obtaining the name of the service to be used (class name)
            $className = $this->resolveClassName(Request::get('service_name')));
            
            $this->app->bind('Including\The\Namespace\For\Service', $className);
        }
    }

    protected function resolveClassName($className)
    {
        $resolver = new Resolver($className);
        $className = $resolver->resolveDependencyName();
        return $className;
    }
}
```

So now all the responsibility is for the Resolver class. This class basically use the parameter passed to the constructor to return the full name (with namespace) of the class that is going to be used as an implementation of the Service interface:

```
class Resolver
{
    protected $name;
    public function __construct($className)
    {
        $this->name = $className;
    }

    public function resolveDependencyName()
    {
        //This is just an example, you can use whatever as 'service_one'
        if($this->name === 'service_one')
        {
            return Full\Namespace\For\Class\Implementation\ServiceOne::class;
        }
        
        if($this->name === 'service_two')
        {
            return Full\Namespace\For\Class\Implementation\ServiceTwo::class;
        }
        //If none, so throw an exception because the dependency can not be resolved 
        throw new ResolverException;
    }
}
```

Well, I really hope it helps some of you.

Best wishes!

---------- EDIT -----------

I just realize that it is not a good idea to use the request data directly inside the container of Laravel. It really is going to cause some trouble in the long term.

The best way is to directly register all the possible instances supported (serviceone and servicetwo) and then resolve one of them directly from a controller or a middleware, so then is the controller "who decides" what service to use (from all the available) based on the input from the request.

In the end, it works at the same, but it is going to allow you to work more naturally.

I have to say thanks to rizqi, a user from the questions channel of the slack chat of Laravel.

He personally created a golden [article](http://rizqi.id/laravel-registry-pattern) about this. Please read it because it solves this issue completely and in a very right way.

[laravel registry pattern](http://rizqi.id/laravel-registry-pattern)

Answer (score 5):

The fact that you define that your controller works with `ServiceInterface` is ok

If you have to choose the concrete implementation of the service basing on a previous step  (that, as i've understood, happens in a previous request) storing the value in session or in database is right too, as you have no alternative: to choose the implementation you have to know the value of the input

The important point is to 'isolate' the resolution of the concrete implementation from the input value in one place: for example create a method that takes this value as a parameter and returns the concrete implementation of the service from the value:

```
public function getServiceImplementation($input_val)
{
    switch($input_val)
    {
        case 1 : return new Service1();
        case 2 : return new Service2();
    }    
}
```

and in your controller:

```
public function controllerMethod()
{
    //create and assign the service implementation
    $this->service = ( new ServiceChooser() )->getServiceImplementation( Session::get('input_val') );
}
```

In this example i've used a different class to store the method, but you can place the method in the controller or use a Simple Factory pattern, depending on where the service should be resolved in your application

Comment: Thanks for that. In fact i just wanted to be sure if use the session is a right approach, I doubted because get access to the session is not easy from the Laravel container (resolution of dependencies), but I just discovered that in fact I can use a Factory approach in order to perform that in a more "natural" way

Answer (score 3):

It's an interesting problem. I'm currently using Laravel 5.5 and have been mulling it over. I also want my service provider to return a specific class (implementing an interface) based upon user input. I think it's better to manually pass the input from the controller so it's easier to see what's going on. I would also store the possible values of the class names in the config.
So based upon the Service classes and interface you've defined above i came up with this:

/config/services.php

```
return [
    'classes': [
        'service1' => 'Service1',
        'service2' => 'Service2',
    ]
]
```

/app/Http/Controllers/MainController.php

```
public function index(ServiceRequest $request)
{
    $service = app()->makeWith(ServiceInterface::class, ['service'=>$request->get('service)]);
    // ... do something with your service
}
```

/app/Http/Requests/ServiceRequest.php

```
public function rules(): array
    $availableServices = array_keys(config('services.classes'));
    return [
        'service' => [
            'required',
            Rule::in($availableServices)
        ]
    ];
}
```

/app/Providers/CustomServiceProvider.php

```
class CustomServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot() {}

    public function register()
    {
        // Parameters are passed from the controller action
        $this->app->bind(
            ServiceInterface::class,
            function($app, $parameters) {
                $serviceConfigKey = $parameters['service'];
                $className = '\\App\\Services\\' . config('services.classes.' . $serviceConfigKey);
                return new $className;
            }
        );
    }
}
```

This way we can validate the input to ensure we are passing a valid service, then the controller handles passing the input from the Request object into the ServiceProvider. I just think when it comes to maintaining this code it will be clear what is going on as opposed to using the request object directly in the ServiceProvider.
PS Remember to register the CustomServiceProvider!

Answer (score 2):

I find the best way to deal with this is using a factory pattern. You can create a class say `ServiceFactory` and it has a single method `create()` it can accept an argument which is used to dynamically choose which concrete class to instantiate.

It has a case statement based on the argument.

It will use `App::make(ServiceOne::class)` or `App::make(ServiceTwo::class)`.depending on which one is required.

You are then able to inject this into your controller (or service which depends on the factory).

You can then mock it in a service unit test.

Comment: Yes, it is the best way to go. I  used the same approach, following the article shared on the original response: http://rizqi.id/laravel-registry-pattern

Answer (score 2):

Recently, I had to implement a similar logic where I was to implement a method to perform mobile top-ups for multiple networks in our application. So, I decided to implement the logic using Factory and Bridge pattern. Factory to create an instance of the concrete Service class based on the user input, and then, the Bridge pattern to set closely related classes into separate hierarchies and route the request to the respective class.

In the controller's method, both Factory and Service classes are injected. The `TopUpServiceFactory's` create method creates an object of the concrete class. The `TopUpService` class then routes the request to that concrete class method.

```
class TopUpController extends Controller
{
        public function topUp(Request $request, TopUpServiceFactoryInterface $serviceFactory, TopUpServiceInterface $topUpService)
        {
              $serviceFactory->create($request->networkCode);
              $topUpService->TopUp($request->all());
        }
}
```

The `TopUpServiceFactoryInterface` and `TopUpServiceInterface` are bound to `TopUpServiceFactory` and `TopUpService` concrete Classes respectively in Service Container.

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind(TopUpServiceFactoryInterface::class, TopUpServiceFactory::class);
        $this->app->bind(TopUpServiceInterface::class, TopUpService::class);
    }
}
```

The create method accepts user input and creates an object of the respective class based on the user input.

```
class TopUpServiceFactory implements TopUpServiceFactoryInterface
{
    public function create(string $networkCode)
    {
        switch ($networkCode) {
            case 'network1':
                app()->bind(NetworkServiceInterface::class, Network1Service::class);
                break;
            case 'network2':
                app()->bind(NetworkServiceInterface::class, Network2Service::class);
                break;
            default:
                app()->bind(NetworkServiceInterface::class, DefaultNetworkService::class);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

The Service Class then picks the object of NetworkService Class and forwards the request.

```
class TopUpService implements TopUpServiceInterface
{
    public function topUp(array $requestParams)
    {
        $networkService = app()->get(NetworkServiceInterface::class);
        $networkService->topUp($requestParams);
    }
}
```

All network's concrete classes implement a common interface `NetworkServiceInterface`, which is used to inject dependency dynamically, implementing *Liskov Substitution Principle*

```
class Network1Service implements NetworkServiceInterface
{
    public function topUp(array $requestParam)
    {
        Process Topup ......
    }
}

class Network2Service implements NetworkServiceInterface
{
    public function topUp(array $requestParam)
    {
        Process Topup ......
    }
}
...
```