# How to DRY optional app feature in Laravel context

Tags: laravel

For example we have two features: Access Groups, Target Groups and there may be added others in future.
Also we have Company entity to which User entity related 1:M (Company to User).

So in different places of the codebase we need to check if some of these features enabled for Company (as well for User): in Request classes, Query classes (i.e. Repositories, Queries, or even Models, depends on your chooses), Actions/Commands/Services, etc.

Clearly everywhere repeated checking like below isn't accepted by DRY.

```
if ($user->company->access_groups_feature_enabled) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

There must be one place with checking if one or another feature is enabled/disabled, in the same place we should choose correct Requests/Services/Repositories/etc, so if feature Access Groups enabled we should load *RequestImplyingAccessGroups*, *SomeEntityLikeUserRepositoryImplyingAccessGroup*, *ShowNewsServiceImplyingAccessGroups*, and so on (please don't bother about naming, it's just for example to understand what I mean).

The same is for Target Groups and other features. Then we should use these classes by common interface dependency-injecting them to agnostic classes somehow.

I think it may be done on Middleware level but I'm a little bit confused right now.

Are there any best practice for such case? How did you implement it in your projects?

Also I found Fowler's article about that: https://martinfowler.com/articles/feature-toggles.html
But I think I am a little bit confused to apply it for laravel infrastructure.

Comment: Use middleware to check if the said feature is enabled or not. There, you can do all sort of things with the request; return the user back, Make changes to request object, choose between Request/Services/Repository,etc.

Comment: @QumberRizvi well but how then should I "tell" IOC from middleware to inject right Service/Repository on feature enabled/disabled?

Comment: Can you check if the feature is enable at __construct() of the middleware? Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36853791/laravel-dynamic-dependency-injection-for-interface-based-on-user-input) help you?

Comment: @QumberRizvi yes, i think the provided link clears it, thanks!